# How do I create a link to open an ssh connection

Tags: unix, ssh, symlink

I am trying to create a link to open an ssh connection to another computer.  I am an OS X 10.5.7 and Ubuntu 9.04 user.  I am tempted to create a symbolic link as such:

ln -s "ssh user@computer_name" computer_name

I know this is wrong.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick the command in a bash file somewhere and symbolic link to that.

Answer (score 4):

you can create an alias somewhere in the file your shell runs when it starts (i.e. `.bashrc` for bash):

```
alias computer_name="ssh user@computer_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way:
open `.ssh/config` and past this template

```
Host your_alias_for_remote_server
   Hostname 0.0.0.0
   User user_name
   Compression yes
```

Now you can type ssh your_alias_for_remote_server and you will be immediately connected with your server

Comment: nice suggestion, much better than an alias in bash

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Edit ~/.profile and add the following:

```
computer_name(){
    ssh user@computer_name
}
```

Log out of the Terminal and reopen the Terminal. The command "computer_name" should now work.